# Receiving custom data from AWS SES webhook events as we do in sendgrid?

Tags: webhooks, sendgrid, amazon-ses

I need to get custom data as part of email events (open, click, etc) sent from AWS SES.

For sendgrid I do (Java)

```
    Personalization personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.addCustomArg("event_type", "SubscriptionDeliveryEmailEvent");
    personalization.addCustomArg("event_source_type", "SubscriptionDelivery");
    mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
```

How can I do the same for AWS SES? I couldn't even find a mention to it. (Java preferred pls :D)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as simple as it is in SendGrid. You will need set something up with SNS. Refer here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/

Answer (score 0):

AWS SES doesn’t provide any type of webhook out of the box for any type of event (open, click...)